# Using Ctrl + N, Intellij cannot find a class in a maven dependency unless it's specified in the pom

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I've just raised a corresponding issue [**here**](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-113045).

The issue is, if I try to search for a class which is inside a maven dependency, then Intellij (EAP Cardea v. 132.27 running using jdk1.7.0_25) cannot seem to find this class even with the 'Include non-project classes' checked.

[image]

The class in question is PoolableConnectionFactory in the following depedency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
```

However, as soon as I add to the project's pom, the class is found.

[image]

I have already tried doing an 'Invalidate Caches and Restart' and have also tried re-indexing the local maven repo *after* deleting Intellij's system folder.

My maven settings are as follows:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was under the wrong impression that IntelliJ searched for classes in all maven dependencies in the local/index repo(s).

This was clarified in the following [Issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-113045#comment=27-579662).